# A few questions about express validation

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I have a few questions about input validation with node, maybe there's a few concepts I'm just misunderstanding and need clarification. I'm currently using express-validator.

I currently have something like:

```
function validate(req) {
req.assert('name', 'Please enter a name').notEmpty()
req.assert('email', 'Please enter an email').notEmpty()

var errors = req.validationErrors();
return errors;
};

app.post('/contactform', function(req, res){
var err = validate(req);

   if (!err) {
        res.send('everything is good to go')
   } else {
       res.send(err)
   }
});
```

I understand the validation part, however how do I go about actually using the information once I sanitize it?

I've tried stuff along the lines of

```
var email = req.sanitize('email').toString()
```

But this just gives me an `[object object]`.

So I have a few questions:

1. How do I actually go about using sanitized strings? or does the express-validator module just validate/sanitize and I need to do something else to actually be able to use the sanitized output?
2. Also, should input be sanitized before being validated for security?

**EDIT:** 
So I looked at the source code for express-validator and I found that the parameters are stored as `req.param('name')` or `req.param('email')`. I'm assuming that if you sanitize and/or validate the parameters and then access them, you receive the sanitized version. This answers my first question, still curious about the second question regarding general security.

Answer (score 0):

I use trim() chained to sanitize():

`var str = req.sanitize('input').trim();`